# Why do I keep getting a Syntax error while working with if statements?

Tags: python

```
country = input("Please enter a country: ")

if country == United Kingdom:
    print("Accents in the United Kingdom change noticeably about every 40km.")

elif country == Italy:
    print("Italy has three active volcanoes: Vesuvius, Etna, and Stromboli.")

elif country == France:
    print("France is the world's most popular tourist destination.")

elif country == Germany:
    print("One-third of Germany is still covered in forests and woodlands.")

elif country == Japan:
    print("In Japanese, the name Japan is Nihon or Nippon, which means Land of the Rising Sun.")

elif country == USA:
    print("100 acres of pizza are served in the United States every day!")

elif country == Canada:
    print("The Royal Montreal Golf Club is the oldest golf club in North America.")

else: 
    print(country + " is currently not a G7 country")
```

I keep getting a syntax error but I can not seem to find my error. 
My error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 3
    if country == United Kingdom:
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: add quotes to the country names., `"USA", "Japan"...`

Answer (score 1):

You need quotes around your string values.

```
if country == 'United Kingdom':
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem after each "==", the syntax is not correct, try adding quotes to each country

```
country = str(input("Please enter a country: "))

if country == "United Kingdom":
    print("Accents in the United Kingdom change noticeably about every 40km.")

elif country == "Italy":
    print("Italy has three active volcanoes: Vesuvius, Etna, and Stromboli.")

elif country == "France":
    print("France is the world's most popular tourist destination.")

elif country == "Germany":
    print("One-third of Germany is still covered in forests and woodlands.")

elif country == "Japan":
    print("In Japanese, the name Japan is Nihon or Nippon, which means Land of the Rising Sun.")

elif country == "USA":
    print("100 acres of pizza are served in the United States every day!")

elif country == "Canada":
    print("The Royal Montreal Golf Club is the oldest golf club in North America.")

else: 
    print(country + " is currently not a G7 country")
```

Comment: Also, as a recommendation, you could process the input to either lowercase or uppercase, as so the countries inside each if/elif (`country.lower()`)